# How to hide success message after some time in contact us page success?

Tags: magento2, contact-us, success-message, timeout

I tried below way to hide a success message after some time in contact us page. But Not working.

> app\code\Eight25media\Messagehide\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages": "Vendor_Module/js/view/messages",
    }
}
}
```

> app\code\Eight25media\Messagehide\view\frontend\web\js\view\messages.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'underscore',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
'use strict';
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: []
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
        }, 5000);
    }
});
});
```

**How can i give a time out to contact us success message?**

Comment: try with -
 var storage = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage;
        storage.remove('messages');

Comment: @AnasMansuri where should i add this in my code?

Comment: replace with - $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
        }, 5000);

Comment: @AnasMansuri sorry, i want to show the message and set a time out to hide the message.